# UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY in my Angular Project

Tags: angular

I get the following messages if I execute this command

```
npm install --save @angular/animations
```

-->

```
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@5.2.5
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@5.2.5
```

My question would be how I con solve it in order to do not get this message or can I ignore this messages?

```
C:\Users\Me\Documents\workspace-vsc-vtaMobileApp\vta-vendor-app>npm install --save @angular/animations
vta-vendor-app@0.0.0 C:\Users\05906\Documents\workspace-vsc-
vtaMobileApp\vta-vendor-app
+-- @angular/animations@5.2.5
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@5.2.5
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@5.2.5

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
....
```

Comment: Did you try to remove `node_modules` folders and redo `npm install`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`npm` doesn't install peer dependency automaticaly. 
So you need to install them manually with `npm install`.

```
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@5.2.5
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@5.2.5
```

**UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY** message said you which ones, you should install/update

In your case, you need to install @angular/compiler and @angular/core.

```
npm install --save @angular/compiler @angular/core
```